# How can I link main menu links to submenu links in Joomla?

Tags: php, joomla, menu

I have main menu with sublinks, so when you click mainmenu link, it should go to default submenu link. For example:

Main menu:
Homepage | Information

Information submenu has 
Contact and Location selections and Contact should be active when Information main menu link is activated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**As I see it, you have two options**

1. If your main menu is also your home page, you could make the submenu the [default menu](http://www.packtpub.com/article/customizing-menus-menu-in-joomla).
2. Modify the main menu to be an [external link](http://www.packtpub.com/article/customizing-menus-menu-in-joomla) to the submenu on your own site.

Answer (score 1):

Use an alias as your menu type and link to the submenu